# Proving an ODE's coefficients are constants

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a N-th order homogenous linear ODE, I need to prove that if both $u(x)$ and $u'(x)$ are a solution to the given ODE then the ODE's coefficients are constants. It is also known that the ODE coefficients have continuous derivatives.

So I know that given the ODE:
$$y^{(n)}+P_{n-1}(x)y^{n-1}+...+P_0(x)y=0$$
for a particular solution $u(x)$:
$$1) \space u^{(n)}+P_{n-1}(x)u^{(n-1)}+...+P_0(x)u=0$$
$$2) \space u^{(n+1)}+P_{n-1}(x)u^{(n)}+...+P_0(x)u'=0$$

Now because it is known that the coefficients have continuous derivatives I thought about derivating the first equation and receive
$$u^{(n+1)}+P'_{n-1}(x)u^{(n-1)}+P_{n-1}(x)u^{(n)}+...+P'_0(x)u+P_0(x)u'=0$$ and if I subtract the second equation for it I get
$$P'_{n-1}(x)u^{(n-1)}+P'_{n-2}(x)u^{(n-2)}+...+P'_0(x)u=0$$
But I don't see how it helps me proving that $P_k(x)$ is constant

---

EDIT:
I just realized but, if $u'(x)$ is a solution so does $u''(x)$ and thus also $u^{(3)}(x)$ and so on including $u^{(n)}$ though I still
don't know if it gives me anything

Comment: How did you get your Eq. 2)?

Comment: @Marcel "I need to prove that if both () and ′() are a solution to the given ODE then the ODE's coefficients are constants", 2) is just assuming $u'(x)$ also solve the equation

Comment: How about trying to obtain 2) by deriving 1) with respect to $x$?

Comment: @Marcel deriving 1) gives the third equation with $P'_k$

Comment: For linear differential operators $D[\cdot]$ we have $\left(D[u]\right)'=D'[u]+D[u']$

Comment: @Cesareo to what are you referring? In the third equation I did $(P_k(x) u^{(k+1)})'=P'_k(x)u^{(k+1)} + P_k(x)u^{(k)}$